# Echo before a process starts

Tags: php, copy, system, fork

I would like (after form submission) to print some HTML code before the entire PHP process completes. The code below opens the window only after the the copy() and the system() are done:

```
<script language="javascript">
window.open("copyProgress.php?source=<?php echo $_POST['element_100'];?>","","width=400,height=400,resizable=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no");
</script>

<?php

sleep(3);

//move the file to the net disk
if(copy($tempUploadDir."\\".$_POST['element_100'], $dir.$subfolder."\\".$filename)) { 
    unlink($tempUploadDir."\\".$_POST['element_100']);  
} else {   
    die("problem with uploading file. ".$tempUploadDir."\\".$_POST['element_100']);
}

system("x264.exe $args");

?>
```

Could you please suggest what to do to get the HTML (JS) code shown (and work) first?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Flush the PHP output buffer with `ob_flush()`.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Comment: I've tried it, but no success.. what I did is: 'ob_start();' at the start of the document, then 'ob_flush(); flush(); sleep(3);' before and even after the JS. Unfortunately, no change. What I did wrong?

Comment: moreover, after I submit the form, it shows the form page until the end of the process instead of at least route to the new page according to the "action" in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirection to some other page like

```
$redirect = "http://www.example.com/";
header( 'Location: '.$redirect );
```

and execute just javascript there first, and after a few second redirect back to this page with just php. 
The problem is that javascript won't get executed before server completes it's work and gets HTML to the client side.